# Input stopping threads from running

Tags: python, multithreading, input, python-multithreading

I want to run a program that can ask for input *and* run threads at the same time.

For example:

```
import threading

def get_input():
  while True:
    var = input('prompt> ')
    do_stuff

#main loop
while True:
  input_thread = threading.Thread(target=get_input)
  input_thread.start()
  do_stuff_that_doesn't_work
```

So the problem above would be that it asks for `input(prompt>)` and while it's asking for input, `do_stuff_that_doesn't_work` won't work.
I've seen people get by this before but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: get input and do stuff is very important in my code. When a client connects to the server (my code is the server code), a prompt should come up, while accepting new connections at the same time. The problem is that it can't accept connections if the input is blocking the other threads. Do you know how to avoid the blocking? maybe it would be good if the input always stayed at the bottom of the command line while the output is being written above it? is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be creating a thread inside your while loop.  Try this code...

```
import threading
import time

run = True
def get_input():
    global run
    while run:
        var = input('prompt> ') #python 3 only
        print('Input was ', var)
        if 'q' == var:
            run = False

input_thread = threading.Thread(target=get_input)
input_thread.start()

print('Type q to exit')
ctr = 0
while run:
    ctr += 1
    time.sleep(0.1)
print('Exiting with ctr: ', ctr)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but the above code was just an example. In my code I need the thread to be initialized in a loop.

Comment: You can do that but you shouldn't be spinning up multiple threads that are calling `input` in an infinite `while` loop like you do at the top.  You only have one system wide input so you need to have the first thread exit before starting another one.

Comment: but i want to know how to unblock. The example doesn't really matter (I might have explained it wrong anyways), I just want to know how to get by the blocking.

Comment: The original example (as written) doesn't block.  The code after the `input_thread.start()`runs.  That's the whole point of a thread.  As for exiting the first thread before starting a new one, of course you don't have too but it's very bad coding practice to have multiple threads reading from the same input pipe, not to mention you're piling up zombie threads this way.  This may cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: I am sorry for the example code again. the problem is that I don't want multiple threads for input but I don't know where to put the thread to get input. I want to get input after things happen in the main loop but only start the thread once. I could use a Boolean but then I still have the blocking problem.